# Adding django id to a list

Tags: python, django, list, unicode

I am trying to store django id to a list. But it stores two digit number as separate two digits. For example it stores 10 as 1 and 0. It stores the values as unicode characters.  Can any one help me

```
   def practice_view(request, id=None):
        msg = ''
        if request.method == 'POST':
            questions = request.POST.get('Que');
            list = [];
            result = [];
            total = 0;
            for i in questions:
                if i.isdigit():
                    list.append(i)
                total = total + 1;
    During debugging this is what it displays
    Que=u'[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]'
    questions=u'[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]'
    list=[u'6', u'7', u'8', u'9', u'1', u'0', u'1', u'1', u'1', u'2']
```

Comment: 1. avoid use list for variable names. 2. Convert the string to int before appending to a list.

Comment: try `questions = request.POST.getlist('Que')` instead of `request.POST.get`. This will only work if you are sending multiple values with name `Que` in your post data.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this,

```
import ast
def practice_view(request, id=None):
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        questions = ast.literal_eval(request.POST.get('Que'))
        lst = [];
        result = [];
        total = 0;
        for i in questions:
            if type(i) == 'int':
                lst.append(i)
            total = total + 1;
```

Since the value of query string param `Que` is a string, python should iterate over each char exists inside the string.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Tried it. But still its the same. While storing in the list a 2 digit number is stored as separate two digits. For ex. 10 as 1 and 0.

Comment: what's the output of `print questions` ?

Comment: questions contains [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] but when it is appended to list it is stored as [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,0,1,1,1,2]

Comment: post the output of `type(questions)`